# Testing ITelephony endCall on AVD throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have no problem executing call blocking codes when the OS is Marshmallow and above but testing it on Kitkat in AVD throws `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony.endCall`

```
public interface ITelephony {

     void endCall();
     void silenceRinger();

}
```

These are the permissions used:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

This is being executed in a BroadcastReceiver:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());

Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
m.setAccessible(true);      

ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);

telephonyService.silenceRinger();
telephonyService.endCall();
```

This is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.8.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
}
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle ?

Comment: @AlexandreGombert posted already.

Answer (score 0):

This method is no longer available in this class as of API 29. There is also no replacement. I've checked all methods available from this class. It's probably connected to the fact that it was also removed from TelecomManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#endCall(). Handling calls with a custom dialler would still work.